# Time machine backups not recognised after OS upgrade

Tags: snow-leopard, time-machine, backup, macos, time-capsule

I finally updated my OS from 10.6.8 to Mavericks 10.9 yesterday on my late 2009 iMac 27", but when I got to the point of switching back on my Time machine (connected to a time capsule 2 Tbytes) it doesn't see the previous backups.

How can I make Time machine see the previous backups?  Also: Can I continue on the same time capsule to add to the backups I was doing under 10.6.8 ?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the backup has changed a lot between 10.6.8 and 10.9. There were several upgrades and some newer versions recognised backups from previous versions. This could be one of reasons why Apple recommends upgrades for each new OS sequentially.

If you continue backups, most likely Time Machine will do one of two:

- override your current backup
- create a new backup bundle

I am not sure what it chooses and when but I had both those cases happening. If you do not need old backups, just remove them. If you need them, you can move them to a subfolder.

One more solution for you could be to remove and add a Time Machine disk. Sometimes that helps Time Machine to recognise that the drive has backups. Logic of Time Machine is very strange sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The first time -after the upgrade - you are going to use the Time Machine disk, at least the window should appear.

[image]